# sprintf() segmentation error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I have a segmentation fault in my program. Here is my code

```
char buffer[5000]="";
memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
sprintf(buffer,"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\
                        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:log=\"http://wsdlclass.wsdlcreat.sims.triesten.com\">\
                        <soap:Header>\
                        </soap:Header>\
                        <soap:Body>\
                        <log:saveMessBillingDetails>\
                        <log:userId>%s</log:userId>\
                        <log:billNo>%s</log:billNo>\
            <log:billingAmount>%s</log:billingAmount>\
            <log:billingDate>%s</log:billingDate>\
            <log:messId>%s</log:messId>\
            <log:itemId>%s</log:itemId>\
            <log:ipAddress>%s</log:ipAddress>\
            <log:schoolId>%s</log:schoolId>\
                        </log:saveMessBillingDetails>\
                        </soap:Body>\
            </soap:Envelope>",
  "00007", "152555", "42.00", "17-08-2013", 10, "CHKK", "10.10.1.164", 1);
```

Comment: In addition to the %s // %d error: 1) the memset() is useless 2) I strongly advise to use snprintf() instead, and check its return value 3) for large s[n]printf() calls like this, the code can be madeeasier to read and maintain, by splitting up the snprintf() call into multiple calls to snprintf()

Comment: Please don't change the question to the correct version. People may wonder what the error is.

Comment: FYI: I rolled it back to its previous version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the `*printf*()` family of functions you need to take care that **number** and **type** of conversion specifiers match the arguments following the format "string".

This is not the case in your call to `sprintf()`, as there are only `"%s"` where as also integers (which require `"%d"`) are passed in. However the number of arguments is correct.

**Update:**

Are correct and secure version of your code could be:

```
char buffer[5000]="";
int printed = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:log=\"http://wsdlclass.wsdlcreat.sims.triesten.com\">\
  <soap:Header>\
  </soap:Header>\
  <soap:Body>\
  <log:saveMessBillingDetails>\
  <log:userId>%s</log:userId>\
  <log:billNo>%s</log:billNo>\
  <log:billingAmount>%s</log:billingAmount>\
  <log:billingDate>%s</log:billingDate>\
  <log:messId>%d</log:messId>\
  <log:itemId>%s</log:itemId>\
  <log:ipAddress>%s</log:ipAddress>\
  <log:schoolId>%d</log:schoolId>\
  </log:saveMessBillingDetails>\
  </soap:Body>\
  </soap:Envelope>",
  "00007", "152555", "42.00", "17-08-2013", 10, "CHKK", "10.10.1.164", 1);

  if (printed >= sizeof(buffer))
    fprintf(stderr, "The target buffer was to small.\n");
```

Comment: Yeah i have integer in it. sorry edited it now. If i have integer what shoulf i use. please advice.

Comment: @Krish: Please see my answer, I mentioned this in there. Also reading `man 3 printf` might help getting enlighted.

Comment: @Krish: It is **not a good idea to correct sources here in SO after having fund the errors**. This makes the ansers/discussions difficult to understand afterwards.

Comment: Actually am very sorry @alk. I have both integer and string need to be copied into it. do i need to use snprintf ??

Comment: `snprintf()` could protect you from overwriting the target buffer! Again, please read the documantation: http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=printf&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en

Comment: @Krish: So it seems it's time to learn how to use a debugger. Which platform are you compiling/running this code on?

Comment: am compiling this in fedora using gcc and running it on a handheld device used for printing receipts..  so i cant use a debugger here..

Comment: If your target has no built-in debugging interface, eg. JTAG, and you cannot spot source bugs like this example, you are essentially in deep brown stuff.  Did you expect to just have code magically work on the target?

Comment: @Krish: There is bug in my example. Find it and I will correct it ... it is easy to find, you just need to count.

Comment: @MartinJames the provider said i can install Gdb in the target but they havn't given me the proper way to installing it in it..i think you may understand the situation am in.. i dont have option thats why i came here.. if you are not interested then dont comment and blame others.People come here to get help and help each others not to blame others.. if you can help me then do it,.. i will appreciated that.

Answer (score 3):

Change `10` and `1` to `"10"` and `"1"` since the corresponding conversion specifiers of `sprintf` are `%s` which expects strings.

Or you can change the corresponding specifiers from `%s` to `%d`.